# How can you specify docker flags when a step is ran on Google Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, pytorch, google-cloud-build

I need to be able to specify `--ipc=host` to the docker command that runs a step. How do I do that?

A little more context.... When running the tests in one of my Google Cloud Build steps I am running into this error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected bus error encountered in worker. This might be caused by insufficient shared memory (shm).
```

This error is common when using `pytorch`, like I am, in docker but it is easily addressed with the flag `--ipc=host`. I don't know where to put this flag in my step's settings in the `cloudbuild.yml`.

Right now my step looks like this:

```
- id: 'run-tests'
  name: 'gcr.io/project/app:test-$BRANCH_NAME'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - './bin/run-tests.sh'
```

I have tried adding the `"ipc=host"` to the `args` but those go to `bash` and not the `docker` command running the image.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try this option out myself, but I think you can build a container with `ipc=host` set. There is no option to do so during a `docker build`, but you can run a container with `ipc=host`, then create a new image using `docker commit`.

The basic premise is:

```
docker build
docker run --ipc=host
docker commit
docker push
```

More details and discussion here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24743

**5/4 Edit**

While this works, the host may have the default shm setting, so you won't get a larger size. Instead, you should probably use `docker run --shm-size=256m` or similar to give your docker container more shared memory. This requires you to use the docker cloud builder image and configure your own docker run command.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker` builder is documented here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/docker/README.md#run-a-docker-image

And customizing steps is explained here:

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration#creating_a_build_config

Specifically step #4

I assume you're wanting the equivalent of:

```sh
docker run .... --ipc=host ...
```

So:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args:
  - "run"
  - ...
  - "--ipc=host"
  - ...
```

Comment: Thanks Daz.. the above makes sense when using `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker` but in this case I'm using an image to run the tests.  The `args` doesn't seem to be the right place for this. I've updated my description to provide a bit more context on what step I'm trying to extend. Thanks for looking/helping!

Comment: It's an interesting question. I think (don't know) you cannot do this. Cloud Build is using a container runtime to run each of the steps. Presumably, Google wishes to control this runtime to prevent bad behaviors. It may not even be that Google is using Docker Engine as this runtime; it may well be running an alternative or variant. I reviewed the Cloud Build configuration spec [link](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config) and there's nothing obvious that would provide what you need.

Comment: I suppose the **run-tests.sh** is already part of your image, isn’t it? Couldn’t you still run it through the **docker run** command like @DazWilkin suggested? In the **args** field it would look something like `args: ['run', '--ipc=host', 'gcr.io/[PROJECT]/[IMAGE]', 'bash', './bin/run-test.sh']`.